# android: how to return

Tags: android, return, oncreate

this is rather a very rare question and quite an unusual one.. In my onCreate () method, i first check if sd-card is mounted or not. if it is unmounted then i simply use return; so that no further code can be executed and the user is presented with an alert diaglog where the user can select retry or exit. i used return; in onCreate because I didn't want to process the rest of the code otherwise it might generate errors. Now I want to know two things

When I use return; in the onCreate () method, where does it return to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I use return; in the onCreate() method, where does it return to?

onCreate() declares a void return type, so you're not returning a value.  In this case, returning early simply ends execution of the method before the remainder of the code is executed.  In terms of Android, you're returning control back to the system (i.e. UI thread).

**Edit**: Whenever Android runs an application, it creates a process and (at a minimum) one thread (the UI thread) to run your code.  That thread follows the application lifecycle and calls into your code at certain points (activity callbacks).  Whenever your code isn't running, the system is free to process input events that have been queued up.  To sum up a very long winder answer: whenever you return from `onCreate()`, `onResume()`, etc, you have returned control back to the system.

Comment: thnkx for the answer sir. Can you please answer another important question.. Is it possible to return the control back to the system from any other function. For example if I use return inside the onCreate function, it returns the control back to the system. What do I need to do if I want to return the control back to the system or to the UI thread from anyother function like onResume etc..If you can answer this question, it will help me in resolving a big problem.. thnx alot. waiting for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Sounds as if you want to end your activity from inside your OnCreate, you can do this (as you can at any time) by calling finish()

Comment: no I don't want to finish, I want to return to the system or to the UI thread.. i know you would think that it would result in just a blank screen but i am really looking for this because of some reason. Can you please help me in this issue. Please read the previous answer. it will help you in understanding what I really want.. I shall be thankful to you if you help me out here..